# How to get Facebook ads_management permission approved

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have built an app that uses the ads_management permission to pause a Facebook ad. I am currently trying to submit it for review.

As part of the review process, the Facebook review team must test this functionality for themselves, in addition to submitting a screencast and text description of how the permission will be used.

The problem is that Facebook has disabled the ability to make test accounts. I reached out to support, and they have asked me to create a real Facebook 'test' account without any personal information. I have done this now three times and attempted to run an ad on this account, the account gets suspended very quickly. I've tried making sure that the account seems as real as possible, added a real credit card number, etc. and it keeps getting banned.

1. I've asked Facebook direct support about this and it's been over three weeks with no reply from them. They just say that it's an issue and they're looking into it whenever I ask. I don't think they're actually going do anything.
2. I don't want to give the Facebook review team my personal account for fear of getting banned (they test from random countries)
3. I've already tried over 12 times to submit my app for a review and see if it could get approved without the reviewer actually testing the pausing step.

How can I get this ads_management approved?